# using excel to edit every field in a column by removing any starting zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula, serial-number

I have multiple excel columns filled with serial numbers from different overlapping databases Im trying to compile them all and remove overlapping numbers to create a unified data base. I've had success using excel formulas to compare the lists to remove duplicates. however the last issue that is one of the lists I'm pulling from has added "0", "00", or "000" in front of some but not all of its serial numbers. Which threw off my comparison and left some duplicates. the list is too long for me to go over manually or even with control + F. Is there a formula I could use to remove starting 0s? I dont mind if i have to use it 3 times. or if you have a different solution I'm all ears. Thanks for any help. I'm horrible with excel.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the serial numbers supposed to be the same length?
If they are same length, say length x, you can remove leading zeroes with formula =RIGHT( [serial number], x)

Comment: sadly they arnt

Answer (score 0):

`NUMBERVALUE` should do the trick

[image]

Comment: Note: This assumes the serial numbers are not alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no more than 3 `0`s at the start of the serial numbers you could use the following formula:

```
=CHOOSE((--(LEFT(A1,1)="0"))+(--(LEFT(A1,2)="00"))+(--(LEFT(A1,3)="000")+1),A1, RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1), RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2), RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))
```

(where `A1` is the cell with the serial number)